# Unable to fetch source from Git via SSH in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to use SSH to connect to a remote Git repo (in a Bitbucket private instance, for example, which won't allow HTTPS connections from outside its network) in Visual Studio Team Services

The dialog presented for "Get Sources" is quite unspecific about what is and isn't acceptable when setting up a Git repo source (see screenshot below):

[image]

Obviously these aren't the expected fields for setting up an SSH connection, but I tried setting up a pure SSH connection from the _admin/_services screen, and while I was able to save an SSH service endpoint there, it is not selectable from the Get Sources build step.

I tried following [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34313.visual-studio-team-services-connecting-a-bitbucket-repository.aspx) tutorial but it seems a bit out of date and inaccurate (his/her screenshots show SSH but ultimately end up using HTTPS on the screen I show above)

What are the possible options for using an external Git connection in Visual Studio Team Services? And if SSH is indeed not possible with this tool, are there any workarounds besides allowing HTTPS access?

Comment: You can clone that remote repository by using Command Line step (Tool: git.exe path, argument: clone [ssh url]. Note: I am create SSH key in build server and the build agent running as integrative mode)

Comment: OK, I did not know about the Command Line step, but I don't think that will work still. In order for it to authenticate with ssh, a key pair is required. Where would you specify that in this case?

Comment: I am using the on premise build agent as integrative mode, I can clone the git repository by running the command manually, so it can clone that repository too during the build.